# In Scala 2.8, how to write (append) a line to a file? Should I use Java clesses or there are native Scala functions for this?

Tags: scala, file-io

In Scala 2.8, how to write (append) a line to a file? Should I use Java clesses or there are native Scala functions for this?

If you can also tell how to replace or remove a particular line from a text file - it'd be also interesting.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604237/how-to-write-to-a-file-in-scala

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using java classes or waiting for scala 2.9's scala.io