# How to write to a file in Scala?

Tags: scala, file-io, scala-2.8

For reading, there is the useful abstraction `Source`. How can I write lines to a text file?

Comment: If you know how to do so in Java then you can use the same in Scala.  Is your question specifically with the Scala standard library?

Comment: @wheaties yes best way to do this in scala

Comment: This library is really good: https://github.com/pathikrit/better-files

Comment: Lihaoyi's OS-Lib library https://github.com/lihaoyi/os-lib

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Edit 2019 (8 years later), [Scala-IO](https://github.com/jesseeichar/scala-io) being not very active, if any, [Li Haoyi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/871202/li-haoyi) suggests his own library [`lihaoyi/os-lib`](https://github.com/lihaoyi/os-lib), that he [presents below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56310893/6309).

June 2019, [Xavier Guihot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9297144/xavier-guihot) mentions in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55440822/6309) the library [**`Using`**](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/util/Using$.html), a utility for performing automatic resource management.

---

Edit (September 2011): since [Eduardo Costa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/608693/eduardo-costa) asks about Scala2.9, and since [Rick-777](https://stackoverflow.com/users/204313/rick-777) comments that [scalax.IO commit history](https://github.com/eengbrec/Scalax.IO/commits/master) is pretty much non-existent since mid-2009...

**[Scala-IO](http://jesseeichar.github.io/scala-io-doc/0.4.3/index.html#!/overview)** has changed place: see its [GitHub repo](https://github.com/jesseeichar/scala-io), from [Jesse Eichar](https://github.com/jesseeichar) (also [on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/150272/jesse-eichar)):

> The Scala IO umbrella project consists of a few sub projects for different aspects and extensions of IO.
>   There are two main components of Scala IO:
>
> - **Core** - Core primarily deals with Reading and writing data to and from arbitrary sources and sinks. The corner stone traits are `Input`, `Output` and `Seekable` which provide the core API.
>     Other classes of importance are `Resource`, `ReadChars` and `WriteChars`.
> - **File** - File is a `File` (called `Path`) API that is based on a combination of Java 7 NIO filesystem and SBT PathFinder APIs.
>     `Path` and `FileSystem` are the main entry points into the Scala IO File API.

```
import scalax.io._

val output:Output = Resource.fromFile("someFile")

// Note: each write will open a new connection to file and 
//       each write is executed at the begining of the file,
//       so in this case the last write will be the contents of the file.
// See Seekable for append and patching files
// Also See openOutput for performing several writes with a single connection

output.writeIntsAsBytes(1,2,3)
output.write("hello")(Codec.UTF8)
output.writeStrings(List("hello","world")," ")(Codec.UTF8)
```

---

Original answer (January 2011), with the old place for scala-io:

If you don't want to wait for Scala2.9, you can use the [scala-incubator / scala-io](https://github.com/scala-incubator/scala-io) library.
(as mentioned in "[Why doesn't Scala Source close the underlying InputStream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762843/why-doesnt-scala-source-close-the-underlying-inputstream)")

See [the samples](https://github.com/scala-incubator/scala-io/blob/master/scala-io/src/samples/samples.scala)

```
{ // several examples of writing data
    import scalax.io.{
      FileOps, Path, Codec, OpenOption}
    // the codec must be defined either as a parameter of ops methods or as an implicit
    implicit val codec = scalax.io.Codec.UTF8


    val file: FileOps = Path ("file")

    // write bytes
    // By default the file write will replace
    // an existing file with the new data
    file.write (Array (1,2,3) map ( _.toByte))

    // another option for write is openOptions which allows the caller
    // to specify in detail how the write should take place
    // the openOptions parameter takes a collections of OpenOptions objects
    // which are filesystem specific in general but the standard options
    // are defined in the OpenOption object
    // in addition to the definition common collections are also defined
    // WriteAppend for example is a List(Create, Append, Write)
    file.write (List (1,2,3) map (_.toByte))

    // write a string to the file
    file.write("Hello my dear file")

    // with all options (these are the default options explicitely declared)
    file.write("Hello my dear file")(codec = Codec.UTF8)

    // Convert several strings to the file
    // same options apply as for write
    file.writeStrings( "It costs" :: "one" :: "dollar" :: Nil)

    // Now all options
    file.writeStrings("It costs" :: "one" :: "dollar" :: Nil,
                    separator="||\n||")(codec = Codec.UTF8)
  }
```

Comment: What about a Scala 2.9 version? :)

Comment: The scalax project seems dead (no commits since June 2009). Is this right? [scalax commit history](https://github.com/eengbrec/Scalax.IO/commits/master)

Comment: @Eduardo: I have completed my answer with the new place for scala-io library (which has been updated for Scala2.9: https://github.com/jesseeichar/scala-io/issues/20)

Comment: @Rick-777: That is true. See my revised answer, with the new place for scala-io library.

Comment: Is this really the current suggestion for Scala 2.10? Use Scala IO? There isn't anything in core Scala yet?

Comment: @Phil Scala 2.10 will have one version of Scala IO in it: http://daily-scala.blogspot.fr/2012/07/scala-io-getting-started.html

Comment: I've never used scalax.io, but judging from these example lines, it seems that its API design is pretty bad. Mixing methods for character and binary data in one interface makes little sense and will very likely lead to encoding bugs that are hard to find. The design of java.io (Reader/Writer vs. InputStream/OutputStream) seems much better.

Answer (score 215):

This is one of the features missing from standard Scala that I have found so useful that I add it to my personal library.  (You probably should have a personal library, too.)  The code goes like so:

```
def printToFile(f: java.io.File)(op: java.io.PrintWriter => Unit) {
  val p = new java.io.PrintWriter(f)
  try { op(p) } finally { p.close() }
}
```

and it's used like this:

```
import java.io._
val data = Array("Five","strings","in","a","file!")
printToFile(new File("example.txt")) { p =>
  data.foreach(p.println)
}
```

Comment: new java.io.PrintWriter() uses the platform default encoding, which probably means that the result file is not very portable. For example, if you want to produce a file that you can later send around by email, you should probably use the PrintWriter constructor that allows you to specify an encoding.

Comment: @JonaChristopherSahnwaldt - Sure, in special cases you might want to specify the encoding.  The default for the platform is the most sensible default on average.  Same as with `Source` (default encoding by default).  You can of course add e.g. a `enc: Option[String] = None` parameter after `f` if you find this a common need.

Comment: @RexKerr - I disagree. One should specify the encoding in almost all cases. Most encoding errors I encounter happen because people don't understand or don't think about encoding. They use the default and don't even know it because too many APIs let them get away with it. Nowadays, the most sensible default would probably be UTF-8.

Maybe you only work with English and other languages that can be written in ASCII. Lucky you. I live in Germany and had to fix more broken umlauts than I care to remember.

Comment: @JonaChristopherSahnwaldt - This is a reason to have a sensible default encoding, not to force everyone to specify it all the time.  But if you're on a Mac and your files written by Java are gobbledygook because they aren't Mac OS Roman encoded, I'm not sure it's doing more good than harm.  I think it's the platforms' fault that they haven't agreed on a charset.  As an individual developer, typing in a string is really not going to solve the problem.  (All developers agreeing on UTF-8 would, but then that can just go in as the default.)

Comment: @JonaChristopherSahnwaldt +10 for fixing all the broken umlaut. Can't use a hammer, maybe a hole punch? Or are they already holes that need filling, maybe this guy can help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E-eBBzWEpwE But seriously, the influence of ASCII is so damaging in the world, agree it should be specified, and default as UTF-8

Comment: Any idea what the NIO version of this would be?

Comment: @JanacMeena - NIO just dumps bytes to a file with `Files.write` so you can just create a string, `getBytes` on it (probably asking for UTF-8 encoding), and pass that to `Files.write`.  It's one-liner, albeit kind of a big one.

Answer (score 51):

Similar to the answer by Rex Kerr, but more generic. First I use a helper function:

```
/**
 * Used for reading/writing to database, files, etc.
 * Code From the book "Beginning Scala"
 * http://www.amazon.com/Beginning-Scala-David-Pollak/dp/1430219890
 */
def using[A <: {def close(): Unit}, B](param: A)(f: A => B): B =
try { f(param) } finally { param.close() }
```

Then I use this as:

```
def writeToFile(fileName:String, data:String) = 
  using (new FileWriter(fileName)) {
    fileWriter => fileWriter.write(data)
  }
```

and

```
def appendToFile(fileName:String, textData:String) =
  using (new FileWriter(fileName, true)){ 
    fileWriter => using (new PrintWriter(fileWriter)) {
      printWriter => printWriter.println(textData)
    }
  }
```

etc.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I like your code and it is very educational, but the more I see such constructs for simple problems, the more it reminds me about old "hello world" joke: http://www.ariel.com.au/jokes/The_Evolution_of_a_Programmer.html :-) (+1 vote from me).

Comment: If you're writing one-liners, nothing at all matters. If you're writing significant programs (large with an ongoing need for maintenance and evolution), this kind of thinking leads to the most rapid and pernicious kind of software quality degradation.

Comment: Not everyone is going to have "scala eyes" until some level of practice -- it is funny to see this code example is coming from "Beginning" Scala

Comment: asyncwait "beginning" scala...the most ironic title ever,note: I've the book...and just now I'm beginning to understand it..I suppose than I was a step before "beginner" lol :D ........

Comment: The problem is less the Scala tricks here, but the verbosity and poor style.  I've edited this to much more readable.  After my refactor it's just 4 lines (well, 4 with IDE line lengths, used 6 here to fit in the screen). IMHO it is now very nice answer.

Comment: @Jus12 : Don't forget to call fileWriter.close() 


def writeToFile(fileName:String, data:String) = 
  using (new FileWriter(fileName)) {
    fileWriter => {
              fileWriter.write(data)
              fileWriter.close()
           }
  }
`

Comment: @SandroAthaide `finally { param.close() }` takes care of closing. In fact, that is the only reason for using `using`.

Comment: Took me a while to understand this, but now that I do, it feels quite natural. Is `using` modeled after the python "`with` ... `as`"?

Comment: @mitchus I'm guessing it's based on C#'s `using` statement.  See samthebest's answer for a clearer, more idiomatic implementation.

Answer (score 38):

A simple answer:

```
import java.io.File
import java.io.PrintWriter

def writeToFile(p: String, s: String): Unit = {
    val pw = new PrintWriter(new File(p))
    try pw.write(s) finally pw.close()
  }
```

Comment: @samthebest could you add the libraries you `import` from?

Comment: As of java 7, use java.nio.file instead:                                                  def writeToFile(file: String, stringToWrite: String): Unit = {
    val writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(file))
    try writer.write(stringToWrite) finally writer.close()
  }

Answer (score 18):

Giving another answer, because my edits of other answers where rejected.

This is the **most concise and simple answer** (similar to Garret Hall's)

```
File("filename").writeAll("hello world")
```

This is similar to Jus12, but without the verbosity and with correct [code style](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/)

```
def using[A <: {def close(): Unit}, B](resource: A)(f: A => B): B =
  try f(resource) finally resource.close()

def writeToFile(path: String, data: String): Unit = 
  using(new FileWriter(path))(_.write(data))

def appendToFile(path: String, data: String): Unit =
  using(new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(path, true)))(_.println(data))
```

Note you do NOT need the curly braces for `try finally`, nor lambdas, and note usage of placeholder syntax. Also note better naming.

Comment: Sorry, but your code is imaginable, it does not fulfill the `implemented` prerequisite. You cannot use the code that is not implemented. I mean that you must tell how to find it since it is not available by default and not well-known.

Answer (score 16):

Unfortunately for the top answer, Scala-IO is dead. If you don't mind using a third-party dependency, consider using my [OS-Lib library](https://github.com/lihaoyi/os-lib). This makes working with files, paths and the filesystem very easy:

```
// Make sure working directory exists and is empty
val wd = os.pwd/"out"/"splash"
os.remove.all(wd)
os.makeDir.all(wd)

// Read/write files
os.write(wd/"file.txt", "hello")
os.read(wd/"file.txt") ==> "hello"

// Perform filesystem operations
os.copy(wd/"file.txt", wd/"copied.txt")
os.list(wd) ==> Seq(wd/"copied.txt", wd/"file.txt")
```

It has one-liners for [writing to files](https://github.com/lihaoyi/os-lib#oswrite), [appending to files](https://github.com/lihaoyi/os-lib#oswriteappend), [overwriting files](https://github.com/lihaoyi/os-lib#oswriteover), and many other useful/common operations

Answer (score 15):

Here is a concise one-liner using the Scala compiler library:

```
scala.tools.nsc.io.File("filename").writeAll("hello world")
```

Alternatively, if you want to use the Java libraries you can do this hack:

```
Some(new PrintWriter("filename")).foreach{p => p.write("hello world"); p.close}
```

Comment: What imports? ie where is File coming from?

Comment: The Scala compiler library.

Comment: No longer viable (not in Scala 2.11)

Comment: What are you talking about? `scala.tools.nsc.io.File("/tmp/myFile.txt")` works in Scala 2.11.8.

Comment: It's now in scala.reflect.io.File

Answer (score 13):

One liners for saving/reading to/from `String`, using `java.nio`.

```
import java.nio.file.{Paths, Files, StandardOpenOption}
import java.nio.charset.{StandardCharsets}
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

def write(filePath:String, contents:String) = {
  Files.write(Paths.get(filePath), contents.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), StandardOpenOption.CREATE)
}

def read(filePath:String):String = {
  Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(filePath), StandardCharsets.UTF_8).asScala.mkString
}
```

This isn't suitable for large files, but will do the job.

Some links:

[java.nio.file.Files.write](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write%28java.nio.file.Path,%20byte%5B%5D,%20java.nio.file.OpenOption...%29)
[java.lang.String.getBytes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28java.nio.charset.Charset%29)
[scala.collection.JavaConverters](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.JavaConverters$)
[scala.collection.immutable.List.mkString](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List)

Comment: Why isn't this suitable for large files?

Comment: @ChetanBhasin Probably because `write` will copy `contents` to a new byte array instead of streaming it to the file, thereby at its peak using up twice as much memory than `contents` alone.

Answer (score 10):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, the standard library provides a dedicated resource management utility: [`Using`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/util/Using$.html).

It can be used in this case with resources such as [`PrintWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) or [`BufferedWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html) which extends [`AutoCloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) in order to write to a file and, no matter what, close the resource afterwards:

- For instance, with [`java.io`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) api:

  ```
  import scala.util.Using, java.io.{PrintWriter, File}

  // val lines = List("hello", "world")
  Using(new PrintWriter(new File("file.txt"))) {
    writer => lines.foreach(writer.println)
  }
  ```
- Or with [`java.nio`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html) api:

  ```
  import scala.util.Using, java.nio.file.{Files, Paths}, java.nio.charset.Charset

  // val lines = List("hello", "world")
  Using(Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get("file.txt"), Charset.forName("UTF-8"))) {
    writer => lines.foreach(line => writer.write(line + "\n"))
  }
  ```

Answer (score 8):

A micro library I wrote: https://github.com/pathikrit/better-files

```
file.appendLine("Hello", "World")
```

or

```
file << "Hello" << "\n" << "World"
```

Comment: Here as well -  This question is one of the top hits when googling how to write a file with scala -- now that your project has gotten bigger, you might want to expand your answer a bit?

Answer (score 6):

UPDATE on 2019/Sep/01:

- Starting with Scala 2.13, prefer using [scala.util.Using](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/Using$.html)
- Fixed bug where `finally` would swallow original `Exception` thrown by `try` if `finally` code threw an `Exception`

---

After reviewing all of these answers on how to easily write a file in Scala, and some of them are quite nice, I had three issues:

1. In the [Jus12's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5218279/501113), the use of currying for the using helper method is non-obvious for Scala/FP beginners
2. Needs to encapsulate lower level errors with `scala.util.Try`
3. Needs to show Java developers new to Scala/FP how to properly nest *dependent* resources so the `close` method is performed on each dependent resource in reverse order - **Note:** closing dependent resources in reverse order **ESPECIALLY IN THE EVENT OF A FAILURE** is a rarely understood requirement of the [`java.lang.AutoCloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) specification which tends to lead to very pernicious and difficult to find bugs and run time failures

Before starting, my goal isn't conciseness. It's to facilitate easier understanding for Scala/FP beginners, typically those coming from Java. At the very end, I will pull all the bits together, and then increase the conciseness.

First, the `using` method needs to be updated to use `Try` (again, conciseness is not the goal here). It will be renamed to `tryUsingAutoCloseable`:

```
def tryUsingAutoCloseable[A <: AutoCloseable, R]
  (instantiateAutoCloseable: () => A) //parameter list 1
  (transfer: A => scala.util.Try[R])  //parameter list 2
: scala.util.Try[R] =
  Try(instantiateAutoCloseable())
    .flatMap(
      autoCloseable => {
        var optionExceptionTry: Option[Exception] = None
        try
          transfer(autoCloseable)
        catch {
          case exceptionTry: Exception =>
            optionExceptionTry = Some(exceptionTry)
            throw exceptionTry
        }
        finally
          try
            autoCloseable.close()
          catch {
            case exceptionFinally: Exception =>
              optionExceptionTry match {
                case Some(exceptionTry) =>
                  exceptionTry.addSuppressed(exceptionFinally)
                case None =>
                  throw exceptionFinally
              }
          }
      }
    )
```

The beginning of the above `tryUsingAutoCloseable` method might be confusing because it appears to have two parameter lists instead of the customary single parameter list. This is called currying. And I won't go into detail how currying works or where it is *occasionally* useful. It turns out that for this particular problem space, it's the right tool for the job.

Next, we need to create method, `tryPrintToFile`, which will create a (or overwrite an existing) `File` and write a `List[String]`. It uses a `FileWriter` which is encapsulated by a `BufferedWriter` which is in turn encapsulated by a `PrintWriter`. And to elevate performance, a default buffer size much larger than the default for `BufferedWriter` is defined, `defaultBufferSize`, and assigned the value 65536.

Here's the code (and again, conciseness is not the goal here):

```
val defaultBufferSize: Int = 65536

def tryPrintToFile(
  lines: List[String],
  location: java.io.File,
  bufferSize: Int = defaultBufferSize
): scala.util.Try[Unit] = {
  tryUsingAutoCloseable(() => new java.io.FileWriter(location)) { //this open brace is the start of the second curried parameter to the tryUsingAutoCloseable method
    fileWriter =>
      tryUsingAutoCloseable(() => new java.io.BufferedWriter(fileWriter, bufferSize)) { //this open brace is the start of the second curried parameter to the tryUsingAutoCloseable method
        bufferedWriter =>
          tryUsingAutoCloseable(() => new java.io.PrintWriter(bufferedWriter)) { //this open brace is the start of the second curried parameter to the tryUsingAutoCloseable method
            printWriter =>
              scala.util.Try(
                lines.foreach(line => printWriter.println(line))
              )
          }
      }
  }
}
```

The above `tryPrintToFile` method is useful in that it takes a `List[String]` as input and sends it to a `File`. Let's now create a `tryWriteToFile` method which takes a `String` and writes it to a `File`.

Here's the code (and I'll let you guess conciseness's priority here):

```
def tryWriteToFile(
  content: String,
  location: java.io.File,
  bufferSize: Int = defaultBufferSize
): scala.util.Try[Unit] = {
  tryUsingAutoCloseable(() => new java.io.FileWriter(location)) { //this open brace is the start of the second curried parameter to the tryUsingAutoCloseable method
    fileWriter =>
      tryUsingAutoCloseable(() => new java.io.BufferedWriter(fileWriter, bufferSize)) { //this open brace is the start of the second curried parameter to the tryUsingAutoCloseable method
        bufferedWriter =>
          Try(bufferedWriter.write(content))
      }
  }
}
```

Finally, it is useful to be able to fetch the contents of a `File` as a `String`. While `scala.io.Source` provides a convenient method for easily obtaining the contents of a `File`, the `close` method must be used on the `Source` to release the underlying JVM and file system handles. If this isn't done, then the resource isn't released until the JVM GC (Garbage Collector) gets around to releasing the `Source` instance itself. And even then, there is only a weak JVM guarantee the `finalize` method will be called by the GC to `close` the resource. This means that it is the client's responsibility to explicitly call the `close` method, just the same as it is the responsibility of a client to tall `close` on an instance of `java.lang.AutoCloseable`. For this, we need a second definition of the using method which handles `scala.io.Source`.

Here's the code for this (still not being concise):

```
def tryUsingSource[S <: scala.io.Source, R]
  (instantiateSource: () => S)
  (transfer: S => scala.util.Try[R])
: scala.util.Try[R] =
  Try(instantiateSource())
    .flatMap(
      source => {
        var optionExceptionTry: Option[Exception] = None
        try
          transfer(source)
        catch {
          case exceptionTry: Exception =>
            optionExceptionTry = Some(exceptionTry)
            throw exceptionTry
        }
        finally
          try
            source.close()
          catch {
            case exceptionFinally: Exception =>
              optionExceptionTry match {
                case Some(exceptionTry) =>
                  exceptionTry.addSuppressed(exceptionFinally)
                case None =>
                  throw exceptionFinally
              }
          }
      }
    )
```

And here is an example usage of it in a super simple line streaming file reader (currently using to read tab-delimited files from database output):

```
def tryProcessSource(
    file: java.io.File
  , parseLine: (String, Int) => List[String] = (line, index) => List(line)
  , filterLine: (List[String], Int) => Boolean = (values, index) => true
  , retainValues: (List[String], Int) => List[String] = (values, index) => values
  , isFirstLineNotHeader: Boolean = false
): scala.util.Try[List[List[String]]] =
  tryUsingSource(scala.io.Source.fromFile(file)) {
    source =>
      scala.util.Try(
        ( for {
            (line, index) <-
              source.getLines().buffered.zipWithIndex
            values =
              parseLine(line, index)
            if (index == 0 && !isFirstLineNotHeader) || filterLine(values, index)
            retainedValues =
              retainValues(values, index)
          } yield retainedValues
        ).toList //must explicitly use toList due to the source.close which will
                 //occur immediately following execution of this anonymous function
      )
  )
```

An [updated version of the above function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34283624/501113) has been provided as an answer to a [different but related StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4255021/501113).

---

Now, bringing that all together with the imports extracted (making it much easier to paste into Scala Worksheet present in both Eclipse ScalaIDE and IntelliJ Scala plugin to make it easy to dump output to the desktop to be more easily examined with a text editor), this is what the code looks like (with increased conciseness):

```
import scala.io.Source
import scala.util.Try
import java.io.{BufferedWriter, FileWriter, File, PrintWriter}

val defaultBufferSize: Int = 65536

def tryUsingAutoCloseable[A <: AutoCloseable, R]
  (instantiateAutoCloseable: () => A) //parameter list 1
  (transfer: A => scala.util.Try[R])  //parameter list 2
: scala.util.Try[R] =
  Try(instantiateAutoCloseable())
    .flatMap(
      autoCloseable => {
        var optionExceptionTry: Option[Exception] = None
        try
          transfer(autoCloseable)
        catch {
          case exceptionTry: Exception =>
            optionExceptionTry = Some(exceptionTry)
            throw exceptionTry
        }
        finally
          try
            autoCloseable.close()
          catch {
            case exceptionFinally: Exception =>
              optionExceptionTry match {
                case Some(exceptionTry) =>
                  exceptionTry.addSuppressed(exceptionFinally)
                case None =>
                  throw exceptionFinally
              }
          }
      }
    )

def tryUsingSource[S <: scala.io.Source, R]
  (instantiateSource: () => S)
  (transfer: S => scala.util.Try[R])
: scala.util.Try[R] =
  Try(instantiateSource())
    .flatMap(
      source => {
        var optionExceptionTry: Option[Exception] = None
        try
          transfer(source)
        catch {
          case exceptionTry: Exception =>
            optionExceptionTry = Some(exceptionTry)
            throw exceptionTry
        }
        finally
          try
            source.close()
          catch {
            case exceptionFinally: Exception =>
              optionExceptionTry match {
                case Some(exceptionTry) =>
                  exceptionTry.addSuppressed(exceptionFinally)
                case None =>
                  throw exceptionFinally
              }
          }
      }
    )

def tryPrintToFile(
  lines: List[String],
  location: File,
  bufferSize: Int = defaultBufferSize
): Try[Unit] =
  tryUsingAutoCloseable(() => new FileWriter(location)) { fileWriter =>
    tryUsingAutoCloseable(() => new BufferedWriter(fileWriter, bufferSize)) { bufferedWriter =>
      tryUsingAutoCloseable(() => new PrintWriter(bufferedWriter)) { printWriter =>
          Try(lines.foreach(line => printWriter.println(line)))
      }
    }
  }

def tryWriteToFile(
  content: String,
  location: File,
  bufferSize: Int = defaultBufferSize
): Try[Unit] =
  tryUsingAutoCloseable(() => new FileWriter(location)) { fileWriter =>
    tryUsingAutoCloseable(() => new BufferedWriter(fileWriter, bufferSize)) { bufferedWriter =>
      Try(bufferedWriter.write(content))
    }
  }

def tryProcessSource(
    file: File,
  parseLine: (String, Int) => List[String] = (line, index) => List(line),
  filterLine: (List[String], Int) => Boolean = (values, index) => true,
  retainValues: (List[String], Int) => List[String] = (values, index) => values,
  isFirstLineNotHeader: Boolean = false
): Try[List[List[String]]] =
  tryUsingSource(() => Source.fromFile(file)) { source =>
    Try(
      ( for {
          (line, index) <- source.getLines().buffered.zipWithIndex
          values = parseLine(line, index)
          if (index == 0 && !isFirstLineNotHeader) || filterLine(values, index)
          retainedValues = retainValues(values, index)
        } yield retainedValues
      ).toList
    )
  }
```

As a Scala/FP newbie, I've burned many hours (in mostly head-scratching frustration) earning the above knowledge and solutions. I hope this helps other Scala/FP newbies get over this particular learning hump faster.

Comment: Incredible update. The only problem is that now you have like 100 lines of code which could be replaced with `try-catch-finally`. Still love your passion.

Comment: @Observer I would assert that is an inaccurate statement. The pattern I am describing is actually reducing the amount of boilerplate a _client_ must write to ensure proper handling of closing of AutoCloseables while also enabling the Scala idiomatic FP pattern of using scala.util.Try. If you attempt to achieve the same effects I have by manually writing out the try/catch/finally blocks, I think you will find you end up with quite a bit more boilerplate than you are imagining. So, there is significant readability value in pushing all the boilerplate into the 100 lines of Scala function.

Comment: Sorry if that sounded offensive in any way. Still, my point is that there is no need in such amount of code, because the same could be achieved through non-functional approach with much more simplicity. 
Personally, I'd write try-finally with some additional checks. It's just shorter. 
If I wanted to use wrappers, ApacheUtils are there to use all the dirty work. 
More, all standard Reader/Writers do close underlying streams so your multipwrap is not needed. 

P.S. : I've changed my vote from minus one to plus one to support your efforts. So, please, don't suspect me in a bad intentions.

Comment: No offense taken.

Comment: Remember, you are required to meet the explicit contract of AutoCloseable _regardless_ of how some implementations happen to work right now (ex: Java.io.Reader). The method I designed honors that requirement. Consider that at some point in the future, Reader was changed such that you could no longer depend upon it chaining dependent resource closes. And that is a completely valid design change per the AutoCloseable contract.

Comment: Then, any code using my method above remains functioning and stable. However, any code which left out the close on dependent resources (knowing about the _old_ Java.io.Reader implementation) would have a resource leak and then have to be revisited and refactored. This is why adhering to explicit interface contracts is such a high value.

Comment: I understand your point of view. Thanks for discussion, I have to think about it a bit. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example of writing some lines to a file using [scalaz-stream](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz-stream).

```
import scalaz._
import scalaz.stream._

def writeLinesToFile(lines: Seq[String], file: String): Task[Unit] =
  Process(lines: _*)              // Process that enumerates the lines
    .flatMap(Process(_, "\n"))    // Add a newline after each line
    .pipe(text.utf8Encode)        // Encode as UTF-8
    .to(io.fileChunkW(fileName))  // Buffered write to the file
    .runLog[Task, Unit]           // Get this computation as a Task
    .map(_ => ())                 // Discard the result

writeLinesToFile(Seq("one", "two"), "file.txt").run
```

Answer (score 1):

To surpass samthebest and the contributors before him, I have improved the naming and conciseness:

```
  def using[A <: {def close() : Unit}, B](resource: A)(f: A => B): B =
    try f(resource) finally resource.close()

  def writeStringToFile(file: File, data: String, appending: Boolean = false) =
    using(new FileWriter(file, appending))(_.write(data))
```

Comment: This uses "duck typing" which depends upon reflection. For many contexts, depending upon reflection is a non-starter.

Answer (score 1):

## No dependencies, with error handling

- Uses methods from the standard library exclusively
- Creates directories for the file, if necessary
- Uses [`Either`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/util/Either.html) for error handling

### Code

```
def write(destinationFile: Path, fileContent: String): Either[Exception, Path] =
  write(destinationFile, fileContent.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))

def write(destinationFile: Path, fileContent: Array[Byte]): Either[Exception, Path] =
  try {
    Files.createDirectories(destinationFile.getParent)
    // Return the path to the destinationFile if the write is successful
    Right(Files.write(destinationFile, fileContent))
  } catch {
    case exception: Exception => Left(exception)
  }
```

### Usage

```
val filePath = Paths.get("./testDir/file.txt")

write(filePath , "A test") match {
  case Right(pathToWrittenFile) => println(s"Successfully wrote to $pathToWrittenFile")
  case Left(exception) => println(s"Could not write to $filePath. Exception: $exception")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

2019 Update:

Summary - Java NIO (or NIO.2 for async) is still the most comprehensive file processing solution supported in Scala. The following code creates and writes some text to a new file:

```
import java.io.{BufferedOutputStream, OutputStream}
import java.nio.file.{Files, Paths}

val testFile1 = Paths.get("yourNewFile.txt")
val s1 = "text to insert in file".getBytes()

val out1: OutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(
  Files.newOutputStream(testFile1))

try {
  out1.write(s1, 0, s1.length)
} catch {
  case _ => println("Exception thrown during file writing")
} finally {
  out1.close()
}
```

1. Import Java libraries: IO and NIO
2. Create a `Path` object with your chosen file name
3. Convert your text that you want to insert into a file into a byte array
4. Get your file as a stream: `OutputStream`
5. Pass your byte array into your output stream's `write` function
6. Close the stream

Answer (score 1):

Similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32265975/5826349), here is an example with `fs2` (version 1.0.4):

```scala
import cats.effect._

import fs2._
import fs2.io

import java.nio.file._

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext
import scala.language.higherKinds
import cats.syntax.functor._

object ScalaApp extends IOApp {

  def write[T[_]](p: Path, s: String)
                 (implicit F: ConcurrentEffect[T], cs: ContextShift[T]): T[Unit] = {
    Stream(s)
      .covary[T]
      .through(text.utf8Encode)
      .through(
        io.file.writeAll(
          p,
          scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.global,
          Seq(StandardOpenOption.CREATE)
        )
      )
      .compile
      .drain
  }


  def run(args: List[String]): IO[ExitCode] = {

    implicit val executionContext: ExecutionContext =
      scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

    implicit val contextShift: ContextShift[IO] =
      IO.contextShift(executionContext)

    val outputFile: Path = Paths.get("output.txt")

    write[IO](outputFile, "Hello world\n").as(ExitCode.Success)

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.io.File
import java.io.PrintWriter

val file = new File("tmp/cloudwatch/metric.json")
val writer = new PrintWriter(file);
writer.write(stream);
writer.close();
```

Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

This line helps to write a file from an Array or String.

```
 new PrintWriter(outputPath) { write(ArrayName.mkString("")); close }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are anyways having Akka Streams in your project, it provides a one-liner:

```
def writeToFile(p: Path, s: String)(implicit mat: Materializer): Unit = {
  Source.single(ByteString(s)).runWith(FileIO.toPath(p))
}
```

Akka docs > [Streaming File IO](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-io.html?language=scala#streaming-file-io)