# How do I append to a file in Scala?

Tags: scala

I would like to write a method similar to the following

```
def appendFile(fileName: String, line: String) = {
}
```

But I'm not sure how to flesh out the implementation. Another question on here alludes to Scala 2.9 capabilities but I could not find further details.

Comment: Also see the second example for append here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5218279/243233

Answer (score 50, accepted):

There is no scala-specific IO implementation at the moment, although I understand [one written by Jesse Eichar](http://jesseeichar.github.com/scala-io/) is in incubation. I'm not sure, to what extent this makes use of the new File (path) API in JDK7. Because of this, for now I would go with the simple Java:

```
val fw = new FileWriter("test.txt", true)
try {
  fw.write( /* your stuff */)
}
finally fw.close()
```

Answer (score 19):

There is a cleaner way — without using external dependencies:

```
import scala.tools.nsc.io.File

File("filename").writeAll("hello!") // or appendAll("hello!")
```

or

```
import scala.tools.nsc.io.Path

Path("/path/to/file").createFile().appendAll("hello!")
```

**Update (November 2020)**
These APIs are stable (unlike claims in the comments). They have been around since my original answer in 2015 and they are still present in the [latest release](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.4/scala-compiler/scala/tools/nsc/io/index.html#File=scala.reflect.io.File).

Comment: This isn't public a API, and can be removed at any time, so don't be surprised if your code breaks one day.

Comment: From the library: Note:  This library is considered experimental and should not be used unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: I am just too uncomfortable with not closing the file descriptors. I had a requirement of using io.BufferedSource and was forced to wrap into a Java try{}, to perform the last rites in finally{}.

Comment: The scala.tools.nsc package is for *New Scala Compiler* - this library is intended for creating scala plugins. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20149397/is-it-better-to-use-import-scala-reflect-io-file-or-java-io-file-in-scala

Answer (score 7):

```
val fw = new FileWriter("test.txt", true) ; 
fw.write("This line appended to file!") ; 
fw.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

[os-lib](https://github.com/lihaoyi/os-lib) is the best option for Scala filesystem operations like appending to a file.

Here's how to append "hear me moo" to a file:

```scala
os.write.append(os.pwd/"whatever"/"file1.txt", "\nhear me moo")
```

os-lib is [the best option](https://mungingdata.com/scala/filesystem-paths-move-copy-list-delete-folders/) for filesystem operations because it provides a unified API for all the common functions and also provides a clean API for paths.  The Java APIs for filesystems require you to waste brainpower on low level details and force you to import a lot of code.

Here's a full example that creates a directory, creates a file, and then appends to the file if you'd like to experiment on your local machine:

```scala
os.makeDir(os.pwd/"whatever")
os.write(os.pwd/"whatever"/"file1.txt", "hi there")
os.write.append(os.pwd/"whatever"/"file1.txt", "\nhear me moo")
```