# Delete directory recursively in Scala

Tags: java, scala, file

I am writing the following (with Scala 2.10 and Java 6):

```
import java.io._

def delete(file: File) {
  if (file.isDirectory) 
    Option(file.listFiles).map(_.toList).getOrElse(Nil).foreach(delete(_))
  file.delete
}
```

How would you improve it ? The code seems working but it ignores the return value of `java.io.File.delete`. Can it be done easier with `scala.io` instead of `java.io` ?

Comment: Personally, I feel that for comprehensions are much easier to read: `    for(list <- Option(file.listFiles()) ; child <- list)
      delete(child)
`

Comment: What's the point of creating that Option and mapping through it? What's wrong with simple "file.listFiles.foreach(delete)"?

Comment: @ViliusNormantas The `listFiles` may return `null` so you need to check it for `null` or wrap it with `Option`. Moreover you probably need to distinguish b/w two cases: (1) `listFiles` returns an empty array and (2) `listFiles` returns null (I/O error occurred)

Comment: [os-lib](https://github.com/lihaoyi/os-lib) makes this possible with a one liner: `os.remove.all(os.pwd/"dogs")`.  See my answer for more details.  This library is the easiest way to use a performant solution with an elegantly simple API.  Using the underlying Java libraries, like `java.nio`, directly makes you write code that's complex and ugly.

Comment: @Powers Thanks a lot for suggesting `os-lib`. I use `java.nio` directly but would prefer a nice Scala wrapper instead.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

With pure scala + java way

```
import scala.reflect.io.Directory
import java.io.File

val directory = new Directory(new File("/sampleDirectory"))
directory.deleteRecursively()
```

> deleteRecursively() Returns false on failure

Comment: This is simple and clean when compared to other solutions posted here.

Comment: this does not work, as this gives errors `error: not found: type File`

Comment: @con , make sure to have `import java.io.File`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20158921/4582240 says we should not use "scala.reflect.io" easily?

Answer (score 27):

Try this code that throws an exception if it fails:

```
def deleteRecursively(file: File): Unit = {
  if (file.isDirectory) {
    file.listFiles.foreach(deleteRecursively)
  }
  if (file.exists && !file.delete) {
    throw new Exception(s"Unable to delete ${file.getAbsolutePath}")
  }
}
```

You could also fold or map over the delete if you want to return a value for all the deletes.

Comment: Nice recursive structure.

Answer (score 22):

Using [scala IO](http://jesseeichar.github.io/scala-io-doc/0.4.3/index.html#!/file/delete)

```
import scalax.file.Path

val path = Path.fromString("/tmp/testfile")    
try {
  path.deleteRecursively(continueOnFailure = false) 
} catch {
  case e: IOException => // some file could not be deleted
}
```

or better, you could use a `Try`

```
val path: Path = Path ("/tmp/file")
Try(path.deleteRecursively(continueOnFailure = false))
```

which will either result in a `Success[Int]` containing the number of files deleted, or a `Failure[IOException]`.

Comment: Thank you. I would not like to use any external dependencies though.

Answer (score 13):

From
http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/java-io-faq-how-delete-directory-tree

Using Apache Common IO

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.WildcardFileFilter;
public void deleteDirectory(String directoryName)
throws IOException
{
  try
  {
    FileUtils.deleteDirectory(new File(directoryName));
  }
  catch (IOException ioe)
  {
    // log the exception here
    ioe.printStackTrace();
    throw ioe;
  }
}
```

The Scala one can just do this...

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils
import org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.WildcardFileFilter
FileUtils.deleteDirectory(new File(outputFile))
```

[Maven Repo Imports](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-io/1.3.2)

Answer (score 8):

Using the Java NIO.2 API:

```
import java.nio.file.{Files, Paths, Path, SimpleFileVisitor, FileVisitResult}
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes

def remove(root: Path): Unit = {
  Files.walkFileTree(root, new SimpleFileVisitor[Path] {
    override def visitFile(file: Path, attrs: BasicFileAttributes): FileVisitResult = {
      Files.delete(file)
      FileVisitResult.CONTINUE
    }
    override def postVisitDirectory(dir: Path, exc: IOException): FileVisitResult = {
      Files.delete(dir)
      FileVisitResult.CONTINUE
    }
  })
}

remove(Paths.get("/tmp/testdir"))
```

Really, it's a pity that the NIO.2 API is with us for so many years and yet few people are using it, even though it is really superior to the old `File` API.

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on Vladimir Matveev's NIO2 solution:

```
object Util {
  import java.io.IOException
  import java.nio.file.{Files, Paths, Path, SimpleFileVisitor, FileVisitResult}
  import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes

  def remove(root: Path, deleteRoot: Boolean = true): Unit =
    Files.walkFileTree(root, new SimpleFileVisitor[Path] {
      override def visitFile(file: Path, attributes: BasicFileAttributes): FileVisitResult = {
        Files.delete(file)
        FileVisitResult.CONTINUE
      }

      override def postVisitDirectory(dir: Path, exception: IOException): FileVisitResult = {
        if (deleteRoot) Files.delete(dir)
        FileVisitResult.CONTINUE
      }
    })

  def removeUnder(string: String): Unit = remove(Paths.get(string), deleteRoot=false)

  def removeAll(string: String): Unit = remove(Paths.get(string))

  def removeUnder(file: java.io.File): Unit = remove(file.toPath, deleteRoot=false)

  def removeAll(file: java.io.File): Unit = remove(file.toPath)
}
```

Comment: I packaged this code in a SBT project, so it's easily accessible for folks that have access to Maven: https://github.com/MrPowers/spark-daria/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/github/mrpowers/spark/daria/utils/NioUtils.scala  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Using java 6 without using dependencies this is pretty much the only way to do so.
The problem with your function is that it return Unit (which I btw would explicit note it using `def delete(file: File): Unit = {`

I took your code and modify it to return map from file name to the deleting status.

```
def delete(file: File): Array[(String, Boolean)] = {
  Option(file.listFiles).map(_.flatMap(f => delete(f))).getOrElse(Array()) :+ (file.getPath -> file.delete)
}
```

Comment: One (ok admiittedly long ;) ) liner!

Answer (score 3):

To add to Slavik Muz's answer:

```
def deleteFile(file: File): Boolean = {

  def childrenOf(file: File): List[File] = Option(file.listFiles()).getOrElse(Array.empty).toList

  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(files: List[File]): Boolean = files match {

    case Nil ⇒ true

    case child :: parents if child.isDirectory && child.listFiles().nonEmpty ⇒
      loop((childrenOf(child) :+ child) ++ parents)

    case fileOrEmptyDir :: rest ⇒
      println(s"deleting $fileOrEmptyDir")
      fileOrEmptyDir.delete()
      loop(rest)

  }

  if (!file.exists()) false
  else loop(childrenOf(file) :+ file)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This one uses java.io but one can delete directories matching it with wildcard string which may or may not contain any content within it.

```
 for (file <- new File("<path as String>").listFiles;
        if( file.getName() matches("[1-9]*"))) FileUtils.deleteDirectory(file)
```

Directory structure e.g.
* A/1/, A/2/, A/300/ ... thats why the regex String: [1-9]*, couldn't find a File API in scala which supports regex(may be i missed something).

Answer (score 2):

Getting little lengthy, but here's one that combines the recursivity of Garrette's solution with the npe-safety of the original question.

```
def deleteFile(path: String) = {
  val penultimateFile = new File(path.split('/').take(2).mkString("/"))
  def getFiles(f: File): Set[File] = {
    Option(f.listFiles)
      .map(a => a.toSet)
      .getOrElse(Set.empty)
  }
  def getRecursively(f: File): Set[File] = {
    val files = getFiles(f)
    val subDirectories = files.filter(path => path.isDirectory)
    subDirectories.flatMap(getRecursively) ++ files + penultimateFile
  }
  getRecursively(penultimateFile).foreach(file => {
    if (getFiles(file).isEmpty && file.getAbsoluteFile().exists) file.delete
  })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is recursive method that clean all in directory, and return count of deleted files

```
def cleanDir(dir: File): Int = {

      @tailrec
      def loop(list: Array[File], deletedFiles: Int): Int = {
        if (list.isEmpty) deletedFiles
        else {
          if (list.head.isDirectory && !list.head.listFiles().isEmpty) {
            loop(list.head.listFiles() ++ list.tail ++ Array(list.head), deletedFiles)
          } else {
            val isDeleted = list.head.delete()
            if (isDeleted) loop(list.tail, deletedFiles + 1)
            else loop(list.tail, deletedFiles)
          }
        }
      }

      loop(dir.listFiles(), 0)
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

What I ended up with

```
def deleteRecursively(f: File): Boolean = {
  if (f.isDirectory) f.listFiles match {
    case files: Array[File] => files.foreach(deleteRecursively)
    case null =>
  }
  f.delete()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[os-lib](https://github.com/lihaoyi/os-lib) makes it easy to delete recursively with a one-liner:

```scala
os.remove.all(os.pwd/"dogs")
```

os-lib uses java.nio under the hood, just doesn't expose all the Java ugliness.  See [here](https://mungingdata.com/scala/filesystem-paths-move-copy-list-delete-folders/) for more info on how to use the library.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by excute external system commands.

```scala
import sys.process._


def delete(path: String) = {
  s"""rm -rf ${path}""".!!
}
```

Comment: Please consider adding a comment if you think this post can be improved.