# Scala: Delete Directory Recursively not working

Tags: scala

I am looking at a solution from Garrett Hall from [Delete directory recursively in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25999255/delete-directory-recursively-in-scala#25999465)

```
import scala.reflect.io.Directory
import java.io._

val dir : String = "/tmp/tempdir_prefix5708675182947835848"

def deleteRecursively(file: File): Unit = {
  if (file.isDirectory) {
    file.listFiles.foreach(deleteRecursively)
  }
  if (file.exists && !file.delete) {
    throw new Exception(s"Unable to delete ${file.getAbsolutePath}")
  }
}

deleteRecursively(dir.asInstanceOf(File))
```

this gives error

```
con@VB:~/Scripts/scala$ scala delete_dir.scala
/home/con/Scripts/scala/delete_dir.scala:15: error: T0 does not take parameters
deleteRecursively(dir.asInstanceOf(File))
                                  ^
one error found
```

I've also tried

`deleteRecursively(dir))`

but this gives error

```
con@VB:~/Scripts/scala$ scala delete_dir.scala
/home/con/Scripts/scala/delete_dir.scala:15: error: type mismatch;
 found   : String
 required: java.io.File
deleteRecursively(dir)
```

and also `deleteRecursively(File(dir))`

but this gives

```
con@VB:~/Scripts/scala$ scala delete_dir.scala
/home/con/Scripts/scala/delete_dir.scala:15: error: object java.io.File is not a value
deleteRecursively(File(dir))
```

I am a newb with Scala, and I can't find solutions to this.  I feel like the original poster forgot something to add, like he expected everyone to know, but I don't as I am too inexperienced.

How can I modify the code so that I can pass a directory as a string to be deleted recursively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested the solution on my own machine, but you seem to have made a very easy-to-fix error. Your `deleteRecursively` function accepts an input of type `File`, so you need to pass an argument of type `File`.

There does not appear to be anything wrong with the `deleteRecursively` function itself.

```
val dir : File = new File("/tmp/tempdir_prefix5708675182947835848")

deleteRecursively(dir)
```

Please let me know in the comments if this fix does not solve your problem. I am happy to work with you to solve this problem.

Comment: yep, it was my declaration, which I wasn't familiar with, but am familiar with now. thanks for helping a newb out!