# How to convert Scala Directory (File, Path) to Java java.io.File

Tags: java, scala

I have an instance of `scala.reflect.io.Directory` and I would like to use it as the working directory of a `Process`:

```
val workDirectory : scala.reflect.io.Directory = ???
Process("myCommand", workDirectory)
```

`Process` requires a Java `java.io.File` argument, however. How do I convert the scala `Directory` to a Java `File`? I can see methods like `toFile`, `toAbsolute`, ... but none of them returns what I need (the same applies for Scala `File` or `Path`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there is no scaladoc for this class it is a bit hard to find how to use it, but came across [this](http://xuwei-k.github.io/scala-compiler-sxr/scala-compiler-2.10.0/scala/reflect/io/Directory.scala.html). Also on StackOverflow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20149397/is-it-better-to-use-import-scala-reflect-io-file-or-java-io-file-in-scala).

Which leads to the following working (in a 2.11 REPL):

```
scala> import scala.reflect.io.Directory
import scala.reflect.io.Directory

scala> import java.io.File
import java.io.File

scala> val workDirectory : Directory = Directory(new File("~/temp"))
workDirectory: scala.reflect.io.Directory = ~/temp

scala> workDirectory.jfile
res0: java.io.File = ~/temp
```

**NB:** The link indicates that this is experimental and not really for external use. As such, it might not be the best API to be using, but if you have one for some reason and you have no other way to get an appropriate `File` then it seems the `jfile` attribute will return the underlying `File`.