# How to get the current (working) directory in Scala?

Tags: scala, file, working-directory

How can I get the current directory (working directory) of the executing program in Scala?

Comment: All of the answers of a similar question re Java will work for Scala as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871051/getting-the-current-working-directory-in-java

Comment: [os-lib](https://github.com/lihaoyi/os-lib) is the best modern solution, see my answer for more details.

Answer (score 23):

Use this
`System.getProperty("user.dir")`

**Edit**:
A list of other standard properties can be found here. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html

Comment: If the response is correct, please accept the answer, so other can benefit from it. (A moderator)

Comment: This seems the "most" correct answer of the answers provided, as it's a standard java property and therefore doesn't require the developer know what "." means (although all developers probably do). The java docs provide a definition for the property here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html

Comment: updated the answer with the link provided by @jake. Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

Use `java.nio`:

```
import java.nio.file.Paths
println(Paths.get(".").toAbsolutePath)
```

---

Remark on `scala.reflect.io.File`: I don't see any reason to look into `scala.reflect` packages for such mundane tasks. Getting the current working directory has usually nothing to do with Scala's reflection capabilities. Here are more reasons not to use `scala.reflect.io.File`: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20149397/is-it-better-to-use-import-scala-reflect-io-file-or-java-io-file-in-scala).

Answer (score 5):

Use this:

```
import scala.reflect.io.File
File(".").toAbsolute
```

Comment: Hi Neil, How can I get rid of the "./" part in the absolute path?

Comment: Can you give an example? Intuitively I would just use string pattern search replace to fix that. Maybe there’s a function for it, though. I’m not sure.

Comment: @ruxtain use `File(".").toCanonical` instead.

Answer (score 5):

I use `new java.io.File(".").getAbsolutePath`, but all the other answers work too. You don't really gain anything by using Scala-specific API here over regular Java APIs

Answer (score 4):

```
import scala.sys.process._
val cwd = "pwd".!!  //*nix OS
```

Comment: When I tried this in Spark Scala in an EMR Notebook, I got `cwd: String =
"/
"` which means it's not helping me see the absolute path...

Answer (score 1):

[os-lib](https://github.com/lihaoyi/os-lib) makes it easy to get the current working directory and perform other filesystem operations.  Here's how to get the current directory:

```scala
os.pwd
```

It's easy to build other path objects from `os.pwd`, for example:

```scala
os.pwd/"src"/"test"/"resources"/"people.csv"
```

The syntax is intuitive and easy to remember, unlike the other options.  See [here](https://mungingdata.com/scala/filesystem-paths-move-copy-list-delete-folders/) for more details on how to use the os-lib project.

Comment: have not managed to get the import part working. Added the lib to build.sbt and os is visible in external libraries but importing that to code is not working. How do you do it?

Comment: @juske - you shouldn't need to import anything.  The code is in the `os` package, so `os.pwd` is the full path.  You might just need to reload IntelliJ as you would whenever a dependency is added to the `build.sbt` file.

Comment: thanks for quick reply! still getting an  `error: not found: value os` although there is `sbt: com.lihaoyi:os-lib_2.13:0.78.jar` under external libraries