# Scala Source.fromFile(fileName).getLines().next() misses second character in string line

Tags: scala, file, iterator

Here is the code:

```
val bufferedSource = Source.fromFile("build.sbt")
val lines = bufferedSource.getLines()
bufferedSource.close()
ptintln(lines.next())
```

build.sbt file has such content:

```
name := "timeSeriesMerge"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
```

While debugging program in `lines` I get such string with second character missing:

```
"nme := "timeSeriesMerge""
```

Can anybody explain how is this possible? It misses the second character in the string. Where is the problem? It misses the second character for first line only.

It also would be cool if somebody could explain why this code throws:

```
java.io.IOException: Stream Closed
```

Comment: For the second: you should only close the `Source` after you finished working with `lines`.

Comment: Ok. That helped. Thank you. Any ideas about my first question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your question 1, short answer: use `Source.fromFile("build.sbt").getLines()` directly without using `bufferedSource`, because `bufferedSource` and `lines` sharing same `InputStream`, in debug time, maybe the index has changed by `toString`

**Full Explanation:**

This is caused by **toString** method has changed the `Stream`'s index that shared between `lines` and `bufferedSource` in the **debug time** , As we know when **IDE** stop in the **breakpoint**, it will `invoke` `variable` `toString` methods. like for `lines` and `bufferedSource` variables, it will invoke `Iterator.toString`, output like:

```
override def toString = (if (hasNext) "non-empty" else "empty")+" iterator"
> bufferedSource: non-empty iterator
> lines: non-empty iterator
```

As the above `toString` method, it will invoke `hasNext` firstly, this means it will invoke [iter.hasNext](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/io/BufferedSource.scala#L36) in `BufferedSource`, but there is a problem for `BufferedSource.iter`:

```
  override lazy val iter = (
    Iterator
    continually (codec wrap charReader.read())
    takeWhile (_ != -1)
    map (_.toChar)
  )
```

when check `hasNext` it will read a character from `InputStream`. but this `InputStream` is sharing with `BufferedLineIterator`.

for `val lines = bufferedSource.getLines()` is creating new `BufferedLineIterator` from the `BufferedSource` by [BufferedSource.decachedReader](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/io/BufferedSource.scala#L55) with sharing same [`InputStream` between `BufferedSource`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/io/BufferedSource.scala#L22).

So if we have invoked `hasNext` method on `BufferedSource`, it will change the index on `BufferedLineIterator`.

Below is an example to demonstrate this:

```
  //file content: import Settings._
  val bufferedSource: BufferedSource = Source.fromFile("build.sbt")
  val lines = bufferedSource.getLines()
  bufferedSource.hasNext
  val str = lines.next()
  println(str)
  > mport Settings._
```

As the above example, we manually invoke `hasNext` method, so the `Stream` index has changed to next.

And for when we using **IDE** to debug, it invokes `toString` randomly, so it maybe cause the second character missing by debug in:

https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/io/BufferedSource.scala#L55

Comment: As @AlexeyRomanov commented i need to close Source after i finished working with it. It resolves my problem with `java.io.IOException: Stream Closed`. If i use `Source.fromFile("build.sbt").getLines()` directly without using bufferedSource, how can i close this Source in the end?

Comment: @VovaPolischuk, it's unnecessary to close it by yourself, just leave it, **JVM** will help you do this.

Comment: i read that after jvm shut down, it automatically closes open file. Do you mean this? that about the case when jvm is run for a long time? I would appreciate, if you could live some links or explanation about that

Comment: @cehengpohi, you can leave your comments here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47769957/does-jvm-automatically-closes-files

Comment: @VovaPolischuk, if you don't frequently operate files in your application, you can leave it to **JVM** handle it, if you need open many files in your application, since **scala** doesn't have **try with resource** maybe you want to achieve this like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25634455/simple-scala-pattern-for-using-try-with-resources-automatic-resource-manageme/25634594

Answer (score 2):

Here, You are calling "next" on Iterator after the stream has been closed.

You should close the stream only after you have done using it.
Therefore, the correct sequence of statements should be

```
    println(lines.next())
    bufferedSource.close()
```

Also, if you want to iterate over the complete file, you need to call next inside a loop. You can try -

```
    for(line <- lines){
      println(line)
    }
```