# Does JVM automatically closes files?

Tags: java, scala, file, jvm

Somewhere I read that it's unnecessary to close it by yourself, just leave it, JVM will help you do this. Is it true?

Assume I need to fetch data from file with

```
Source.fromFile(fileName).getLines()
```

directly, without

```
val source = Source.fromFile(fileName)
val lines = source.getLines()
............
source.close()
```

In a first way, I can't get access directly to the source and close it. My JVM works for a long period. And I need a file to be closed (unused resources need to be closed).

It would be great if somebody could leave some links or explanations here.

Comment: "Somewhere I read that it's unnecessary to close it by yourself, just leave it" No, that's why explicit close methods and try-with-resources exist.

Comment: Related: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/33010/do-i-need-to-close-my-fileoutputstreams

Comment: @saifahmad - Incorrect.  They will be *eventually* collected by the GC ... after they become unreachable.  The problem is "eventually".  If you rely on the GC to close files, your application is liable to run out of *file descriptors* before the GC gets a chance to clean up your mess.

Comment: @Stephen C But JVM is intelligent enough to detect that file discriptor is going to fill. And GC would kick-in. But I agree that it's a bad practice to leave a file pointer dangling.

Comment: @saifahmad - I'm pretty sure that the GC will not be triggered if you run out of file descriptors.  (And I just looked at the OpenJDK Java 8 source code ...)

Comment: And I just confirmed it with a simple test program.

Comment: @saifahmad: no, it is not. The JVM itself does not know anything about file descriptors. It doesn’t detect when it runs out of descriptor and it doesn’t trigger a garbage collection. Even worse, a garbage collection running at the same time wouldn’t free them in time. The only thing, the garbage collector does, is detecting that the objects encapsulating the descriptors are garbage. That alone is not sufficient to free them.

Comment: Thanks all for the information. I was unaware of the fact that file descriptor are not considered in the GC.

Comment: You can let the JVM do it **provided** you never create too many file between GCs, however if you make this assumption you never know when this might break your application as it can depend on load. It is much safer to always clean up resources that are Closeable.

Answer (score 7):

> Somewhere I read that it's unnecessary to close it by yourself, just leave it, JVM will help you do this. Is it true?

It is partly true.

If you open a file, use it and then drop the file or stream handle (or whatever you want to call it), AND the GC finds it, THEN the GC will queue the file handle object for finalization.  When the finalization occurs the file handler's `finalize()` method will release the resources; i.e. the file descriptor.

However, it is **a bad idea** to rely on the GC to do this.

- If a file handle is (still) reachable, then the GC won't queue it for finalization.
- You have no way of knowing when the GC is going to run next<sup>1</sup>.
- And when the GC runs, it won't necessarily collect *all* of the garbage<sup>2</sup> (and hence queue *all* lost file handles).
- And objects that are queued for finalization don't get actually finalized until after the GC finishes.  (See @Holger's comment)

Put these four things together, and an application can easily run out of file descriptors before the GC gets around to collecting and closing the abandoned file handles.  If that happens, you are liable to get exceptions on operations that open files, directories, sockets, etcetera.

Here's an example you can run (on Linux / UNIX) to see this happening:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
            new FileInputStream("/etc/motd");
        }
    }
}

$ javac Test.java 
$ java Test 
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: /etc/motd (Too many open files)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at Test.main(Test.java:6)
```

---

<sup>1 - A typical GC only runs when the heap (or part of the heap) reaches a given threshold of "fullness".  If an application doesn't allocate many objects, it can take a long time for the threshold to be reached.</sup>

<sup>2 - Modern JVMs use generational garbage collectors which collect different parts of the heap at different rates.</sup>

Comment: There’s the common confusion of Garbage Collection and Finalization. The Garbage Collector will never invoke `finalize()`, in the best case, it will *enqueue* objects needing finalization. Since 99% of all objects don’t need finalization, JVMs do not care about growing queues of pending finalizations. That’s especially true for applications rapidly allocating new resources, as those application threads have a higher priority as the finalization threads. So even *if* a garbage collector has identified finalizable objects encapsulating descriptors, the JVM might still run out of free descriptors

Answer (score 0):

Yes, In some point it's true, **JVM** will help release the file descriptor when GC in some time with invoking `finalize` method(you can try to verify it by `System.gc()`).

And also totally agree we need to explicitly close `InputStream` when we don't need this and release the **file descriptor**.

but if your application don't frequently operate on file descriptors(file, network io), do we need to care this too? after all, there is `finalize` method.

Yes it's a good practice to `close` it, explicitly release it.

and for OP's problem is very like **Java**'s: how to safely close the `Stream` by `Files.lines`. In **Java**, we can use the **try with resources** handle this. But **Scala** not support this, maybe you can try with `try ... finally` to handle this, like:

```
val reader = Source.fromFile("build.sbt").bufferedReader()
try {
  reader.lines().forEach(line => {
  ...
  })
} finally {
  reader.close()
}
```