# How to deference member fields that have already been initialized when constructor throws an error

Tags: java, constructor

```
class XYZ {

   FileInputStream fis;  //opens a file stream
   DBConnection connection; //this is used to connect to a database

   XYZ(String fileName, String dbName) {
       fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
       connection = getDBConnection(dbName); //assume that this line would throw error
   }
}
```

Consider the following scenario: object of class XYZ is created as XYZ obj = new XYZ() - now during the object creation, when constructor is called, let us assume that fis is successfully initialized, but call to the next statement throws an error.
W.r.t to the above scenario:

1. Does fis contain a valid reference? (since the statement executed successfully but the next statement failed)
2. If fis holds a valid reference, how to ensure that fis would be closed, so as to not have a memory leak (One way would be to define a finalize method for this class, but Java GC does not guarantee finalize() would be called)

Answer (score 3):

> Does fis contain a valid reference? (since the statement executed successfully but the next statement failed)

That is not really the point. The field `fis` doesn't exist after the constructor is "left" because of that exception. But the **object** that `fis` references to, that one is still around.

Until the garbage collector kicks in. When the GC removes that FileInputStream object, it will also return the corresponding file handle to the underlying OS (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47769957/does-jvm-automatically-closes-files) for further details).

The real catch here: you have no idea *when* the GC will kick in to return the file handle.

So, you can either do what the answer suggests (to put a try catch around the second call, and have a `fis.close()` in the catch block). Or you consider other ways of addressing this, for example by **not** having such complex operations taking place in the constructor of the object.

Answer (score 0):

If the creation of the connection fails, `fis` contains a valid reference.
You could try the following in order to resolve this:

```
class XYZ
{
  ...

  public XYZ(String fileName, String dbName)
    throws Exception
  {
    // Initialize attributes; not strictly necessary
    fis = null;
    connection = null;

    // Open fis
    fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);

    // Open connection
    try
    {
      connection = getDBConnection(dbName);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      fis.close();
      fis = null;
      throw e;
    }

  } // constructor

} // class XYZ
```