# analogous Try block to try/finally block in scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

What is the analogous in manners of scala `Try` to:

```
timer.start()
try {
  doThis()
} finally {
  timer.cancel()
}
```

Comment: If you are using something implements the java.lang.AutoCloseable, you can use the code at the answer below to implement a standard "finally" pattern. You can also easily refactor the code in the answer below to retarget it to your specific resource API: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604237/how-to-write-to-a-file-in-scala/34277491#34277491

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Given that an exception inside a `Try` simply creates a `Failure` value (as opposed to transferring control to an outer catch block when using `try`), the code in your original  `finally` block would just need to be executed after the `Try`.
In other words, this will do:

```
timer.start()
val result = Try{
  doThis()
}
timer.cancel()
result
```

As far as I know there is no built-in shortcut that would allow to avoid capturing `result` just to return it as is.

Comment: The second code block is not equivalent. `Try.map` only maps the `Success` case, so if an error occurs, `timer.cancel()` would never get called.

Comment: Now that's embarrasing, I don't know how I managed to be so stupid. Let's say it's because I'm sick today, and forget that. Thanks for spotting this.

Answer (score 6):

Since `Try` won't throw an exception in your program flow I believe just write the following:

```
timer.start()
Try(doThis())
timer.cancel()
```

You can assign `Try(doThis())` to a value and process it further if you wish to process the exception (rather than blindly ignoring it) or the call result.

Comment: Generally you'll want to return the `Try` value

Comment: Agreed, in majority of cases you'd like to know when the exception is thrown and do something with this (therefore my last statement in the response) rather than just blindly ignore it (even if that's only acknowledging the exception being thrown). I've updated my answer to make it more precise.

Comment: note that on fatal error (such as OOM) the "finally" code won't be executed, as fatal error are not being caught by `Try`. But such errors should make the whole app fail anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Despite other answers saying otherwise, the *correct* answer is a `Try` *cannot* be completely analogous to a traditional `try...finally`. The reason for this is `Try` will ignore certain types of exceptions including `InterruptedException`, `ControlThrowable`, and others.

Consider if you use `Try` as recommended by other answers:

```scala
lock.lock()
val t = Try(doStuff()) // Doesn't absorb all types of exceptions!
lock.unlock() // THIS MIGHT BE SKIPPED!!!
t.get
```

If the thread is interrupted during `doStuff()`, then an `InterruptedException` will be thrown, and `Try` will rethrow it instead of creating a `Failure`! This will cause `lock.unlock()` to be skipped (and you'll probably deadlock). The same will happen if `doStuff()` invokes a lambda that invokes a [non-local return](https://tpolecat.github.io/2014/05/09/return.html) (which throws a sub-type of `ControlThrowable`).

This is likely why the standard Scala library does not include a `finally` method in the `Try` class -- because it wouldn't work properly.

However, there is some good news. Scala 2.13 introduces [Using](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/util/Using$.html) which essentially performs a try-with-resources. We can trick this into doing a more general try...finally by using a dummy resource:

```scala
Using(lock.lock())(_ => doStuff())(_ => lock.unlock())
```

And if you don't have anything that is idiomatically performed before the `try`, then you can provide a `Unit` in the first parameter list:

```scala
Using(())(_ => doStuff())(_ => lock.unlock())
```

But in any case, `Try` is not going to do the job.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
Try {
  scala.util.control.Exception.ultimately {
    timer.cancel()
  } {
     doThis()
  }
}
```

?

Comment: Some explanation on ultimately would be great