# How can I add a row in a CSV file with SCALA?

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark-sql

I am using Spark SQL for extracting some information from a JSON file. The question is I want to save the result from the SQL analysis into a CSV file for plotting it with Plateau or with d3.js and I'm not able to add a row which contains the "identifiers" of my columns. For example, if I execute the code which is below, I obtain something like this:

```
val languages = sqlContext.sql(""""<QUERY>"""")
val result = idiomas.map(row => row(0) + "," + row(1))
result.saveAsTextFile(outputDirectory + "/lang")
result.collect.foreach(println)

A,395
B,275
C,106
D,60
```

And what I want is to add an identifier row and obtain this:

```
letter,number
A,395
B,275
C,106
D,60
```

How can I do it?
Thanks!

Comment: Just `println("letter, number")` before the `result.collect` line? Or are you looking for something more complex?

Comment: I'd take a look at https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv

Comment: The important thing for my is saving it, not printing it

Comment: I don't understand very well how to use https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv so I need another explanation of how to use it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write to a file in Scala?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604237/how-to-write-to-a-file-in-scala)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604237/how-to-write-to-a-file-in-scala for how to write to a file in Scala.  Once you get that part down, it's just a question of writing your data and properly interspersing comma and newline literals (if you're not aware, a newline literal is written as `"\n"`, exactly the same as Java)