# Finally equivalent in Scala Try

Tags: scala

```
def doWork() = {
  getLock()
  Try(useResource) match {
    case Success(result) => releaseLock(); result
    case Failure(e: Exception) => releaseLock(); throw e
  }
}
```

I'm trying to idiomatically make sure a lock is released when I exit `doWork`. However as part of that method I may throw an exception, so I can't just release the lock at the end of `doWork`.

It looks like a bit of code smell to have `releaseLock()` repeated twice. I could cut that down by using the traditional Java-style try/catch/finally:

```
def doWork() = {
  getLock()
  try {
    useResource
  } catch {
    case e: Exception => throw e
  } finally {
    releaseLock()
  }
}
```

But I prefer to use Scala's `Try` if possible.

Is there a way to perform "finally" logic from within the framework of `Try`?

Comment: Your two versions aren't the same.  The second one returns the result of `useResource`; the first one discards that value and returns the result of `releaseLock`.

Comment: @Sean For the purposes of the question whatever `doWork` returns isn't really relevant, but I'll update the question to prevent any further confusion.

Comment: If you are using something implements the java.lang.AutoCloseable, you can use the code at the answer below to implement a standard "finally" pattern. You can also easily refactor the code in the answer below to retarget it to your specific resource API: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604237/how-to-write-to-a-file-in-scala/34277491#34277491

Comment: This question/answer is much better than the duplicate.

Answer (score 21):

Just squirrel the `Try` away temporarily:

```
def doWork = {
  getLock()
  val t = Try(useResource)
  releaseLock()
  t.get
}
```