# How to avoid try with Future fromTry

Tags: scala, try-catch, finally

I need to write a future that flushes a stream and closes it. Here is what I tried:

```
def close(ous: OutputStream) = Future.fromTry(Try {
    try {
      ous.flush()
    } finally {
      ous.close()
    }
  })
```

Looks ugly. `try{}finally{}` inside the `Try`. But I need finally block in order to avoid resource leak. Is there a way to rewrite the code in not so ugly way?

Comment: Tried StreamConverters? https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/stream/scaladsl/StreamConverters$.html

Answer (score 1):

Future already captures exceptions returning a Future.failed, there's no need to do fromTry and block, so you can do:

```
Future { out.flush() }.andThen( _=> out.close )
```

( `Future { out.flush() }` will asynchronously flush the stream and `andThen` will get called wether it finishes or fails.

Answer (score 0):

This could be an option i think.

```
def close(ous: OutputStream) = Future.fromTry(Try(ous.flush())) andThen {
    case Success(_) => println("do something here")
    case Failure(_) => ous.close()
}
```

Comment: it should close on the Success too (it's a finally) ?

Answer (score 0):

since you are already using `Try` use pattern match on result to `Try{ stream.flush }` and apply `Try{ stream.close() }`

example,

```
  import java.io.{ByteArrayOutputStream, OutputStream}
  import java.util.Date
  import java.io.ObjectOutputStream
  import scala.concurrent.Future
  import scala.util.Try
  import scala.util.{Failure, Success}
  import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

  def doSomeOperation: OutputStream => Future[String] = (outputStream: OutputStream) =>
    withCleanup(outputStream) {
      Future {
        //1/0
        outputStream.toString
      }
    }

  def withCleanup(outputStream: OutputStream)(fn: Future[String]): Future[String] = {

    val execution = fn

    execution onComplete {
      case Success(_) => cleanup(outputStream)
      case Failure(_) => cleanup(outputStream)
    }

    execution
  }

  def cleanup(outputStream: OutputStream): Try[Unit] = Try {
    outputStream.flush()
    println("flushed")
  } match {
    case _ => Try { 
      outputStream.close()
      println("closed")
    }
  }
```

Then call the function, which will flush and close your stream as well.

```
val stream = new ObjectOutputStream(new ByteArrayOutputStream())    
stream.writeObject(new Date())

scala> doSomeOperation(stream)
res18: scala.concurrent.Future[String] = Future(<not completed>)
flushed
closed
```

Comment: Doesn't doing map here mean if there is an earlier failure it won't close?

Comment: @AndyHayden good catch. updated to attempt closing stream even when main execution or `_.flush()` fails

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me whether this is actually cleaner:

```
def close(ous: OutputStream) = Future.fromTry(
  val flushed = Try { ous.flush() }
  val closed = Try { ous.close() }
  if (closed.isFailure) closed else flushed  // bubble up the correct error
)
```

*Note: This is nearly an equivalent of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33682553/finally-equivalent-in-scala-try) but not quite. Mainly since the .close can fail, and this must be encapsulated in the Try.*